# Is it allowed to 'change'/abuse/override the signature of a block in Objective C as follows?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Is this allowed and why?

```
void (^bar)(NSNumber *) = ^(NSNumber *number) {
    NSLog(@"Value is %@, class is %@.", number, [number class]);
};
bar([NSNumber numberWithInt:10]);

void (^foo)(id) = bar;
foo([NSDate date]);
```

Output is:

```
Value is 10, class is __NSCFNumber.
Value is 2012-05-17 18:54:14 +0000, class is __NSDate.
```

I couldn't find anything related that explains this. Can you provide a link to the objective c blocks specification that covers this?

Currently I'm working on a block based UITableView subclass and it would make things a lot easier, if I'm safe to use this.

Comment: Output _is_, or output _would be_? Because if you tested and that's the actual output, then it's allowed.

Comment: FYI this is called *[covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)*.

Comment: I would use void (^bar)(id) instead if you were to use it like this.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield - absolutely correct, and this is why the OP's code is invalid even though the compiler allows it...

Comment: @zneak Yes, this is the actual output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The underlying reasons this works is a combination of:

[1] Objective-C (and C) is not strongly typed at compile time. While warnings may be produced by the compiler they can usually be silenced by (sometimes type unsafe) casts. Your assignment in this case is invalid as you are assigning a block reference which declares it *requires* an argument value compatible with `NSNumber *` to another block reference which only declares it requires an argument value compatible with `id`. This is type unsafe and will produce *runtime* errors sometimes, see below.

[2] Objective-C runtime message passing is dynamic, that is the target code for a message is determined as the code runs. This means as all your uses of `number` in the block are non-specific to `NSNumber` when you pass an `NSDate` at runtime suitable methods are still located dynamically. However change your `bar` to:

```
void (^bar)(NSNumber *) = ^(NSNumber *number)
{
   NSLog(@"Value is %@, class is %@, int value is %d.", number, [number class], [number intValue]);
};
```

and you will see *runtime* errors.

[3] Both `[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]` and `[NSDate date`] are declared to return values of type `id`, not `NSNumber *` & `NSDate *` as you might expect. This means you don't need `foo`, you can just type:

```
bar([NSDate date]);
```

and get the same result without any warnings... As a further example consider this:

```
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];
NSDate *date = num;         // produces a warning
id erase = num;             // erase type info and do...
date = erase;               // effectively the same assignment, no warning
```

**Take way**: Objective-C is **not** a type safe language, the compiler will in many cases warn you about potential problems, but it will **not do so** in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation. This means, that even if I have an invalid assignment [1], I won't run into any runtime errors as long as I make sure [2] that all my uses of 'number' inside of the block are also possible for the infiltrated class (in this case NSDate).